# Uploading static images to app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having issues uploading static files to my app engine site.  I've tried all various combinations of options in the yaml file with no luck.  What's even stranger is when I uploaded all the images seemed to be there for a couple of minutes and then disappeared.  I can even see from the logs that they were there momentarily.  Everything is working fine locally.

YAML is as follows:

```
application: socialsamplrsite
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on

handlers:

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /css/bootstrap.min.css
  static_files: css/bootstrap.min.css
  upload: css/bootstrap.min.css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: .*
  script: django_bootstrap.py
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Here is the log entry when the image did seem to be there:

```
2012-11-30 01:07:34.199 /img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png 200 24ms 43kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11
203.79.108.219 - - [29/Nov/2012:04:07:34 -0800] "GET /img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png HTTP/1.1" 200 43692 "http://socialsamplrsite.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11" "socialsamplrsite.appspot.com" ms=24 cpu_ms=0
```

And then shortly after:

```
2012-11-30 01:08:51.822 /img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png 404 146ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11
203.79.108.219 - - [29/Nov/2012:04:08:51 -0800] "GET /img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11" "socialsamplrsite.appspot.com" ms=147 cpu_ms=0
```

W 2012-11-30 01:08:51.820
Static file referenced by handler not found: /img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png

Comment: What do mean with: When I uploaded all the images? The static images must be the img folder of your project and are uploaded if you upload your application. And show the log.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I deployed the application and the images seemed to upload successfully.  An example of the logs when the image was there and then seemed to disappear has been added to the question.

Comment: What is the url your are using. In the log is a 404: Not Found. Where is your img folder located.

Comment: Redeploy your app and give the --verbose flag to appcfg.py to make sure the file is being included in the deployment.

Comment: OK thanks - I'll try the redeploy when I get a chance with that flag and let you know.  The url being looked for is https://socialsamplrsite.appspot.com/img/Social-Sampler-Master-Logo-for-web.png.  The img folder with the images sites in the root directory of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML File. Often the naming conventions or jinja2 templating code within a web app can cause such errors. Good luck!

Comment: Well got there in the end.  It seems that putting the "- url: /img
  static_dir: img" after "- url: /css/bootstrap.min.css
  static_files: css/bootstrap.min.css
  upload: css/bootstrap.min.css" is what did the trick.  Pretty annoying bug, very difficult to track down.  Thanks for all the tips and advice, always a learning experience!

Comment: No problem. I agree that such minor, but difficult-to-spot errors can be quite frustrating.